# Using jquery to hide table rows created with repeater

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have a created a table with the repeater, im using itemtemplate and alternatingtemplate.
The item template creates the **tabelrow tag** and the alternating template closes the **tablerow tag**.

Here's an example(I will provide the code further down)
Cells 1 to 3 is created by itemtemplate and 4 to 6 with alternating template.

Cells 1 - 3 has data_id 5 
Cells 4 - 6 has data_id 2
Next row 
Cells 1 - 3 has data_id 7
Cells 4 - 6 has data_id 3

Looking like this
Created first loop with repeater
|*Cell1*|_Cell2_|*Cell3*|_Cell4_|*Cell5*|_Cell6_|
Created second loop with repeater
|*Cell1*|_Cell2_|*Cell3*|_Cell4_|*Cell5*|_Cell6_|

End result
|*Cell1*|_Cell2_|*Cell3*|_Cell4_|*Cell5*|_Cell6_|
|*Cell1*|_Cell2_|*Cell3*|_Cell4_|*Cell5*|_Cell6_|

My questions is that I want too hide certain TD's with Jquery. Let's say I want to hide all TD with data-id= 2, that would be cells 4 to 6 first row.

How can I accomplish that without breaking the table structure, best would be to move everything like this.

Get rid of cells 4 to 6 first row

|*Cell1*|_Cell2_|*Cell3*|_Cell4_|*Cell5*|_Cell6_|
|*Cell1*|_Cell2_|*Cell3*|_Cell4_|*Cell5*|_Cell6_|

This is what it looks after removal for me..

|*Cell1*|_Cell2_|*Cell3*|
|*Cell1*|_Cell2_|*Cell3*|_Cell4_|*Cell5*|_Cell6_|

I want it to look like this
|*Cell1*|_Cell2_|*Cell3*||*Cell1*|_Cell2_|*Cell3*|
|*Cell4*|_Cell5_|*Cell6*|

Is that even possible?

Here's my code..

```
    <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">
    <HeaderTemplate>

    <table cellspacing="0">
    <thead>
    <tr>
     <th scope="col" abbr="Sidor/Artiklar" class="nobg">Sidor/Artiklar</th>
     <th scope="col" abbr="Dual 1.8GHz">MozRank</th>
     <th scope="col" abbr="Dual 1.8GHz">PR</th>
     <th scope="col" abbr="Dual 1.8GHz">Fri tillgång</th>
     <th scope="col" abbr="Dual 2GHz">30 Artiklar(1 om dagen)</th>
     <th scope="col" colspan="2" abbr="Dual 2.5GHz">Välj själv</th>
     <th scope="col" abbr="Sidor/Artiklar" class="nobg">Sidor/Artiklar</th>
     <th scope="col" abbr="Dual 1.8GHz">MozRank</th>
     <th scope="col" abbr="Dual 1.8GHz">PR</th>
     <th scope="col" abbr="Dual 1.8GHz">Fri tillgång</th>
     <th scope="col" abbr="Dual 2GHz">30 Artiklar(1 om dagen)</th>
     <th scope="col" colspan="2" abbr="Dual 2.5GHz">Välj själv</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    </HeaderTemplate>

     <AlternatingItemTemplate>

    <th scope="row" class="spec"><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "namn_domain")%> </th>
    <td class="alt" data_id='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "pr_domain")%>'> 
    <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "moz_domain")%>
    </td>
    <td class="alt" data_id='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "pr_domain")%>'> 
    <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "pr_domain")%>       
    </td>
    <td class="alt" data_id='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "pr_domain")%>'> 
    <input type='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "type_domain")%>' name='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "idtag_domain")%>' value='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "faccess_domain")%>' onclick="calculatePrice();disableTB(this.name);" /> "Fri tillgång" 
    </td>
    <td class="alt" data_id='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "pr_domain")%>'>
    <input type="radio" name='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "idtag_domain")%>' value='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "monthly_domain")%>' onclick="calculatePrice();disableTB(this.name);" /> "En artikel om dagen (30/mån)"
    </td>
    <td class="alt" data_id='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "pr_domain")%>'>
    <input type="radio" name='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "idtag_domain")%>' value="0"  onclick="calculatePrice();enableTB(this.name, this.checked)" />  "Skriv ditt antal själv"
    </td>
    <td class="alt" data_id='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "pr_domain")%>'>
    <input type="text"  name='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "moz_domain")%>' id='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "idtag_domain")%>'  Enabled="false" Width="40px" onkeyup="calculatePrice()" style="background-color:#eeeeee" /> 
    </td>

    </tr>
    </AlternatingItemTemplate>

    <ItemTemplate>


    <tr>

    <th scope="row" abbr="Model" class="spec"><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "namn_domain")%>   </th>
    <td class="alt" data_id='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "pr_domain")%>'>
    <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "moz_domain")%>
    </td>
    <td class="alt" data_id='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "pr_domain")%>'>
    <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "pr_domain")%>       
    </td>
    <td class="alt" data_id='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "pr_domain")%>'>
    <b></b>
    <input type='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "type_domain")%>' name='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "idtag_domain")%>' value='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "faccess_domain")%>' onclick="calculatePrice();disableTB(this.name);" /> "Fri tillgång" 
    </td>
    <td class="alt" data_id='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "pr_domain")%>'>  
    <input type="radio" name='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "idtag_domain")%>' value='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "monthly_domain")%>' onclick="calculatePrice();disableTB(this.name);" /> "En artikel om dagen (30/mån)"
    </td>
    <td class="alt" data_id='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "pr_domain")%>'> 
    <input type="radio" name='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "idtag_domain")%>' value="0"  onclick="calculatePrice();enableTB(this.name, this.checked)" />  "Skriv ditt antal själv"
    </td>
    <td class="alt" data_id='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "pr_domain")%>'>
    <input type="text"  name='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "moz_domain")%>' id='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "idtag_domain")%>'  Enabled="false" Width="40px" onkeyup="calculatePrice()" style="background-color:#eeeeee" /> 
    </td>



    </ItemTemplate>
    <FooterTemplate>
    </table>
    </FooterTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
```

This is my jquery, just messing about getting to understand the function, so this code is obviously not the correct
    function hidetd() {

```
for(var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    $("[data_id=" + i + "]").hide();
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*For* loop is not required in your case. The following jQuery code snippet will hide all the **td** elements with attribute **data_id = 2**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var i = 2;
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("td[data_id='"+ i +"']").hide();
  });
</script>
```

Comment: I know, just fiddling with the code, my real problem is how to do with the table.. so I wont get any borken rows.